# How can I programmatically remove all the datasets that HuggingFace has saved on the disk?

Tags: python, download, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I have downloaded a HuggingFace dataset ([`uonlp/CulturaX`](https://huggingface.co/datasets/uonlp/CulturaX)) with the following Python code:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
ds = load_dataset("uonlp/CulturaX", "ar")
```

It downloaded all the .parquet files of the HuggingFace dataset and also generated the .arrow files after the download was completed:

[image]

- `downloads` contains the .parquet files (original dataset data files and format).
- `uonlp___cultura_x` contains the .arrow files.

How can I programmatically remove all the datasets that HuggingFace has saved on the disk? I want to remove both the generated .arrow files and the original dataset data files. Is there some Python function for that?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of different ways to accomplish this. The most simple is probably using `shutil` from the standard library --

```
import pathlib 
import shutil

home_dir = pathlib.Path.home()
dataset_dir = home_dir / ".cache" / "huggingface" / "datasets"
    
shutil.rmtree(str(dataset_dir))
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to get `/path/to` programmatically?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt updated my answer to include this!